# How can I run a php artisan command in the background from controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to figure out a way I can set a artisan command to run in the background when a user does an action, if I run the artisan call method the browser will just load untill it's done.

What I want to do is would similar this to in the terminal:

```
php artisan fix > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But run it from the controller instead, is that possible?

Btw. I know I could just setup a cronjob to run it, but I really want to run it from the controller.

Comment: `Artisan::call('fix');`

Comment: Use [Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events) maybe

Comment: Lawrence - As I write in the question, the artisan call method, is not running in the background, and makes the user wait for it to be done, before it can move on, that's not the goal :(

Comment: I think you want queues. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues

Comment: ourmandave - indeed that would work, but I need to setup the queues to run, in that case I could just setup a cronjob to run the command. But I really want to just run it from the controller (if possible) :)

Answer (score 3):

You could run a background || async task using laravel **queues**:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues